# How do I test my code to handle UnprocessedItems on a BatchWriteItem?

Tags: node.js, amazon-dynamodb

I've implemented a BatchWriteItem to write several items at a time into a single table of my DynamoDB database. and i have added an exponential backoff algorithm to retry the un-processed items. the function works fine, saving the data properly to Dynamo db table, but I wonder if there is a way test this exponential backoff algorithm since i am unable to generate a response with UnprocessedItems

Following is the working code

```
export const batchWriteTable = async (itemObjs, retryCount = 0, chunkSize = 25) => {
  const buildParams = (table) => JSON.parse(`{"RequestItems": {"${table}": []}}`)
  const queryChunk = (arr, size) => {
      const tempArr = []
      for (let i = 0, len = arr.length; i < len; i += size) {
          tempArr.push(arr.slice(i, i + size));
      }

      return tempArr
  }
  const wait = (ms) => new Promise((res) => setTimeout(res, ms));

  await Promise.all(queryChunk(itemObjs, chunkSize).map(async chunk => {
    if (config.verbose) console.log("Audit data set:", JSON.stringify(chunk))
    let itemParams = buildParams('StatusTable');
    itemParams.RequestItems['StatusTable'] = chunk
    const res = await DB.batchWrite(itemParams).promise()
    
    if(res.UnprocessedItems && res.UnprocessedItems.length > 0) {
      console.log('Inside Retry:',retryCount)
      if (retryCount > 8) {
        throw new Error(res.UnprocessedItems);
      }
      //adding delay to avoid immediate retry
      await wait(2 ** retryCount * 10);
      if (config.verbose) console.log("Retry Data:", JSON.stringify(res['UnprocessedItems']['StatusTable']))
      return batchWriteTable(res['UnprocessedItems']['StatusTable'], retryCount + 1)
    }
  })).catch(function (err) {
    console.log('A promise failed to resolve', err)
    throw err
  })
}
```

I was able to generate  **ProvisionedThroughputExceededException** but it didn't enter inside my exponential backoff algorithm